# What is the best way to compare two product / assembly versions

Tags: vb.net, string, compare

Let us say that a product has an assembly version number of 1.5.4537.56784.  There are plenty of examples of how to retrieve this on SO and in most cases (if you simply want to display the information to the end user) then a default string representation is fine.

I now find myself wanting to compare this assembly number with another (this time most definitely stored as a string as it's in a text file online (but in the same format)) to determine whether the version number stored online is the same as the version number retrieved from the executing assembly or it is in fact greater. The term greater is important, not just different but actively greater.

A simple string compare ought to determine if they are the same but I don't think it would determine greater than.  So what type ought I consider changing these stings to in order to make the greater than comparison.  Or have I missed something obvious with string comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your values by `.` into an Integer array or list, whichever you prefer. Then use a simple `If x > y`  comparison for each position in the collection.

```
Dim myAssemblyVersion = "1.5.4537.56784"
Dim theirAssemblyVersion = "1.5.4827.1"

Dim myIntegers = myAssemblyVersion.Split(".")
Dim theirIntegers = theirAssemblyVersion.Split(".")

Dim isTheirsgreater As Boolean = False
For i = 0 To myIntegers.Count - 1
    If theirIntegers(i) > myIntegers(i) Then
        isTheirsgreater = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: No problem, added a quick sample

Answer (score 2):

I would say the best way to compare versions is to use the comparison operators provided by the `System.Version` class. You can create a new instance of `Version` using the string you found in the text file online. Then you can use the GreaterThan operator to compare it to the version of your application.

```
Dim textVer As String = "1.5.4537.56784"
Dim onlineVer As New Version(textVer)
Dim myVer As Version = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName.Version

If onlineVer > myVer Then
    'Version found online is greater than mine
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  Do you happen to know if this checks all four parts of the version number or just the first three?

Comment: @DomSinclair A quick test shows that it does check the fourth part of the version.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.